# Counting integral using Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am interested in how to count integral using residuums:

So, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is integral.

What I search is : is zero a removable singularity and is his reziduum(-1 st coefficient in Laurent series) equals 0 so his reziduum shall be 0 and so the value of integral??
How to compute this?? And I know that the result is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, I need method. John Conway messed something up. Answer could be how he got that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} = -\pi i$??

Comment: Please try to improve your English, this might help you to get more answers. And explain please: who the hell is `John Conway`? Ever heard the word **please** before?

Comment: http://keats.kcl.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/1130890/mod_resource/content/1/Conway%20J%20--%20Functions%20of%20One%20Complex%20Variable.pdf Standard textbook of Complex analysis.

Comment: @nikola Please give page number so we don't have to go through 114 pages of math to find your problem

Comment: Page 116. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contour integration methods should be explained in any complex analysis book.  It's kind of a long story.  Do you know "the residue theorem" and how it is applied?

Comment: Of course I know. I am just interested in this particular problem.

Comment: @nikola The answer you are looking for is explained on pages 115 and 116 of your book.

Comment: Please read my whole question. I am very clear : I don't know how he got $\int_{\gamma_r} \frac{dz}{z} = -\pi i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He was able to get $\int_{\gamma_r} \frac{dz}{z} = -\pi i$ by parametrizing $\gamma_r$ by $z = re^{it}$, $0\le t \le \pi$ and observing that $\gamma_r$ is oriented clockwise; this results in

$$\int_{\gamma_r} \frac{dz}{z} = - \int_0^\pi \frac{ire^{it}\, dt}{re^{it}} = -\int_0^\pi i\, dt = -\pi i.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I searched for!